# CKeditor - move cursor to next container when reached end of the first one

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, contenteditable, content-editor

Looking for some solution to my big big problem with text edit. Short description below:

Lets say I have two (or more) editable containers. What I need is when you typing on a first container and the cursor reaches end of it, instead expanding it i want it to move to next editable container, it is like in regular Word document, when you reach end of the page it takes cursor to the next page, i need the same thing on two div containers, looking for tips solutions. Is it doable ?

Comment: Please check the link. I think it will help you http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/cursor-position

Comment: It's some extremely old topic about FCKeditor (which had completely different API than CKEditor) and not even the same subject.

Comment: Thx maybe I should ask my question a bit different, actually I do not need to use CKEditor, can use only contenteditable tag and javascript, but this seems to be doable, am I right guys ? btw, thanks a lot for answers, both are usefull.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to use plain contentEditable :D. And it won't help - it will be exactly the same situation. You're looking for a holy grail of editors based on contentEditable - how to split content into multiple pages. It's doable using the [CSS regions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-regions-1/), but only Safari IIRC supports them. Thus, we're keeping fingers crossed for this spec :).